# Comparing a traditional and technology based tool

Tags: experiment-design, wilcoxon-signed-rank, method-comparison, control-group

I am trying to compare a printed word dictionary with a digital dictionary that included added features like sound and video feedback. For this I have selected 60 participants and asked 5 questions (same general questions) with regards to printed and digital one. A likert scale was used to give points to these questions. Then I used Wilcoxon test to test the statistical significance. Is it a good design for a research? I have seen people using dividing respondents to control and experimental group and doing pre/post test design. I couldn't find a way of doing that for dictionary. I just want to know user preference of different features provided and to find whether digital one is better that printed one. Whether my design is ok?

Comment: Did you scramble/ randomly assign the order in which they tried the dictionaries? If so, you did a cross - over study and can Google for that.

Comment: @Björn No. But told the respondents that they need to compare both dictionaries before the start of the study.

Comment: Paired Wilcoxon or something parameter

Comment: ....Something parametric with a random subject effect may be a reasonable choice then.